# Nearest step seekbar discret

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsxRY.png) I have a seekbar with 3 stes.

If I tap (for example) on the black dot, the seekbar will select the second step but the nearest step is the third one.

So, how can I have a seekbar that select the nearest step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. I converted my 3-step seekbar in a 100-step seekbar. I implemented onStopTrackingTouch (see how here: javatpoint.com/android-seekbar-example). I consider 0 as the first state, 50 as second and 100 as tird. If seekbar.getProgress() is <= 33 the progress will be set to 0, else if it is between 33 and 66 progress will be set to 50 and if it is >= 66 progress will be 100